# Mouse offset not correct in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a paint app in HTML5 canvas by which user can paint with mouse. But the issue is that there is a slight mouse pointer offset coming when the user  draws something and the drawing is not exactly in the point where mouse is clicked. I am attaching a relevant portion of my code.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('#board');
this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
function drawOnCanvas() {
var ctx = this.ctx;

var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
// Make it visually fill the positioned parent
canvas.style.width ='100%';
canvas.style.height='80%';
// ...then set the internal size to match
canvas.width  = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;

var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
var last_mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

//for clearing the board
document.getElementById('clr').addEventListener('click', function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}, false);

/* Mouse Capturing Work */
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
    last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

    mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
}, false);


/* Drawing on Paint App */
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
// setTimeout(()=>{
//   ctx.strokeStyle = (writeMode===1)?'blue':'white';  //choose pen or eraser (pen is 1 and eraser is 0)
// },100)

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
}, false);

var root = this;


var onPaint = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    if(root.timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(root.timeout);
        root.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            var base64ImageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            root.socket.emit("canvas-data", base64ImageData);
        }, 1000)
 };
}
```

Someone please give an idea how to correct that

Comment: Check that your CSS isn't messing up with the canvas size.

Comment: I did not add any canvas CSS, I only had adjusted the size of the parent div using CSS to fit the canvas inside

Comment: You do add inline CSS styles on the canvas, using percentages. The styling on the parent will affect the canvas size, for instance if the parent size changes afterward, the canvas will get resized through css but its pixel buffer will still be the one value of init time.